# 4-Wire Strain Gauge Measurement

Tags: measurement, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

I want to accurately measure the resistance of a single strain gauge, unaffected by lead wire resistance and with ratiometric ADC conversion to compensate for excitation drifts.
I know for RTD measurements its common to use a simple circuit like below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkjRIf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Unfortunately this works poorly for strain gauges, since the full swing of the signal is very low, on the order of V_exc/2 +- 10 mV, so a lot of the usable signal vanishes into ADC noise.

Naturally a bridge configuation + instrumentation amplifier comes to mind, but after trying for quite some time I just cannot come up with a decent 4-wire connection. Best I can find is a 3-wire one like this:
[image]

Since there a a lot of 4-wire strain gauge setups available commercially, there must be solution to this that I cannot find. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: This site is not product commercials, however what you are seeking is load cell amplifier or load cell front end with ADC.  This one might fulfil your requests:  https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000385663309.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marko, but thats not what I'm looking for since it needs 4 remote gauges (or 2 + 2 resistors) if Im not mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works by copying the voltage difference at the gauge into a bridge through high input impedance op amps. Might not be the most elegant way but I think it should be OK.

[image: 4 Wire Strain Gauge Circuit]